# How to specify Attachments related list in a VF page?

Tags: visualforce

The Attachments related list isn't showing up, what am i missing here?

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" extensions="EventExtension" tabStyle="Event" standardStylesheets="true" showHeader="true">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Calendar" subtitle="{!IF(ISNULL(Event.Subject),'New Event',Event.Subject)}" />
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Event Edit" mode="edit" tabStyle="Event" >

        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveEvent}" />  
            <apex:commandButton value="Save& New Task" action="{!saveAndNewTask}"/>    
            <apex:commandButton value="Save& New Event" action="{!saveAndNewEvent}"/>                  
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" immediate="true" />                   
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Calendar Details" columns="2">

        </apex:pageBlockSection>        
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
   <apex:relatedList id="noteslist" list="NotesAndAttachments" subject="{!Event.id}" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Your code works for me.  

Is it something like Notes and Attachments are not enabled for Events (which would be bizarre)?

Comment: @amtorVitae when you go to setup--> develope --> API and click on Enterprise are you able to see notesandattachments related event parent objecT?

Comment: @nivyaj Start accepting a solution for some of your questions,most of your questions are having higher votes but no solution has been marked yet. These questions could be more helpful and useful for others if there was an accepted solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer

Try using **list="Attachments"** instead of `list="NotesAndAttachments"`.

```
<apex:relatedList list="Attachments"  subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}" />
```

This sample is working fine for me.

```
<apex:page standardController="Event">
  <apex:detail relatedList="false"/>
  <apex:relatedList list="Attachments"  subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}" />
</apex:page>
```

### Extra Info

I don't know why but `Event` seams not to be related to `Notes`.

I've used this snipped to check:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Event.sObjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.ChildRelationship> relationships = d.getChildRelationships();

String listOfRelationshipNames = '';
for(Schema.ChildRelationship rel:relationships){
    listOfRelationshipNames = listOfRelationshipNames + rel.getRelationshipName() + ', ';
}

System.debug(listOfRelationshipNames);
```

and this are the Event relationships:

> USER_DEBUG [9]|DEBUG|Attachments, null, null,
>   FeedSubscriptionsForEntity, RecurringEvents, Feeds, EventRelations,
>   null, null,

Comment: Awesome, I was going to the Enterprise WSDL and looking for the exact name for notesandattachments, it does say "Attachments"

Answer (score 5):

The relationship name for the Notes and Attachments related list has been changed in winter 14 release.

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!account}"  list="CombinedAttachments" />
```

Based on the following link: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008rzSIAQ

Comment: It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Martin's answer , always a better idea to look at the enterprise WSDL since it is readily available with the current updated schema and easy to access

```
    <complexType name="Event">
<complexContent><extension base="ens:sObject">
<sequence><element name="Account" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:Account"/><element name="AccountId" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
<element name="ActivityDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:date"/>
<element name="ActivityDateTime" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
```

**`<element name="Attachments" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>`**