# How to get Notes and Attachments and Submit for Approval related lists on a Visualforce page for a custom object to override the 'New' button?

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom object that is the object for a particular Approval process. I want to create a Visualforce page for this custom object to override the 'New' button, to design the process of creating a record of this custom object, including adding necessary attachments and then finally submitting the record for approval, as easy as possible with as few clicks as possible.

I have tried a number of different ways, as described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/how-to-specify-attachments-related-list-in-a-vf-page) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008rzSIAQ), but I cannot get the related lists for either Attachments or Approval Process to appear on the Visualforce page as the 'New/Edit' type.

This is my current visualforce code:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Custom_Object_A__c">
<apex:messages />
    <apex:sectionheader title="{!$ObjectType.Custom_Object_A__c.label} Edit" subtitle="{!IF(ISNULL(Custom_Object_A__c.Name), 'Create a new Custom Object record',Custom_Object_A__c.Name)}"/>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock mode="edit" title="{!$ObjectType.Custom_Object_A__c.label} Edit">
            <apex:pageblockbuttons >
                <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageblockbuttons>
            <apex:outputpanel >
                <apex:pageblocksection title="Information" showheader="true" columns="2">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Custom_Object_A__c.Name}" required="true"/>
                </apex:pageblocksection>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>

    <apex:outputpanel >
        <apex:relatedlist list="CombinedAttachments" title="Notes & Attachments"/>
        <apex:relatedlist list="ProcessSteps" title="Approval History"/>
    </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You need to have an Id for those related lists to work. You're going to have to roll your own and then use multiple DML Statements.

Comment: I am just after the 'New Note/New Attachment' button and 'Submit for Approval' button to appear on this VF page. A record of the custom object wouldn't have been created yet, as it's just for the 'New' button. So I was wondering how I could at least get them to appear on the page? Thanks

Comment: That's what I'm saying, you can't use the standard stuff because your record isn't inserted. You're going to have to roll your own. And the submit for approval button also won't work until the record exists in the database.

Comment: OK - thanks. Can you elaborate a bit more on 'roll your own', please?

Comment: I just mean you have to build your own interface to allow the addition of `Attachment` records and approval submission. That seems to non-trivial to add a quick example of what I mean or what it might look like here. It's not going to be the easiest feature to implement.

Comment: `Submit for Approval` is typically done as a Detail Page button, not an override of `New/Edit`;

Comment: You can submit for approval via PB / flow so could use that to handle that portion